# Javascript SQLite transaction loop not incrementing rowsAffected

Tags: javascript, sql, angularjs, sqlite, cordova

I have a custom executeSql statement where I pass an array of queries and an array of parameters to make it run faster in a single transaction. When it executes, I'm able to see the rowsAffected per executeSql is populating correctly (I get some "0 records affected", also some "1 records affected").

After I output that for my own confirmation, I want to keep track of how many records were updated in total. So I just add a counter, then output that value once the loop is done. But the end result is showing me 0 records affected everytime.

What's wrong here?

```
    ExecuteQueryWhereQueryAndParamsBothArrays: function (queryArray, paramsArray, success, fail) {
        var hasError = false;
        var counter = 0;

        $rootScope.db.transaction(function (tx) {
            for (var i = 0; i < paramsArray.length; i++) {
                var query = queryArray[i];
                var params = paramsArray[i];

                tx.executeSql(query, params, function (tx, results) {
                    window.logger.logIt("results.rowsAffected: " + results.rowsAffected); // this is showing the correct results
                    counter += results.rowsAffected;
                }, function() {
                    hasError = true;
                    onError(tx, r);
                });
            }
        });

        if (hasError) {
            fail();
        } else {
            window.logger.logIt("successCounter: " + counter); // this always displays 0 (records)
            success(counter);
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up implementing the transaction callbacks like @frank suggested, but my counters were still 0. Though the results.rowsAffected was always accurate, for some reason the counter variable was never accessible outside the for loop. I ended up implementing global variables ($rootScope.{variablename} for you angular people) and incremented that everytime from the results.rowsAffected and that worked.

```
var inc = function(incCounter) {
   $rootScope.counter = $rootScope.counter + incCounter;
};

    ExecuteQueryWhereQueryAndParamsBothArrays: function (queryArray, paramsArray, success, fail) {
        var hasError = false;
        var counter = 0;

        $rootScope.db.transaction(function (tx) {
            for (var i = 0; i < paramsArray.length; i++) {
                var query = queryArray[i];
                var params = paramsArray[i];

                tx.executeSql(query, params, function (tx, results) {
                    window.logger.logIt("results.rowsAffected: " + results.rowsAffected); // this is showing the correct results
                    inc(results.rowsAffected);
                }, function(tx, r) {
                    hasError = true;
                    onError(tx, r);
                });
            }
        }, function () {
   fail();
}, function () {
   success();
});
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add the following code to the success handler of the `db.transaction` and check the value of counter.

```
var counter = 0;

$rootScope.db.transaction(function (tx) {
...... // Your code.
},errorDB,succesDB)

function successDB(){
  window.logger.logIt("successCounter: " + counter);
  console.log("successCounter: " + counter); // Your counter variable should contain the total
}

function errorDB(err){
 console.log("Error processing SQL:Message:" + err.message + "CODE:" + err.code);
}
```